# i am having problems in doing a loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, numbers

so I'm making a program that needs to pick a number (like 10) then add a loop that adds one unit to my number Everytime. I have tried this :

```
while true :
    num = 10
    num += 1
    print(num)
```

can you help me on this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your example won’t work because you are resetting it to 10 every time.

You have to do so something like this:

```py
num = 10 #Set it to 10 once
while True:
   num += 1 #add 1 each time
   print(num)
```

Note that true is invalid and in python you use True.
Also note that python is based on whitespace so you will **Never** use (bool) in a if statement or a loop. It is just a waste of space to add ()

Comment: yea sorry i used True in my code editor just a mistake here

Comment: No problem @ParsaAd, if this answers your question please mark it as the answer so if anyone else finds your question then they know where the answer is.

Comment: yes i was gonna do but stackoverflow said you need to wait some minutes

Answer (score -1):

Try doing

```
while (true):
    num = 10
    num += 1
    print(num)
```

Comment: umm. but here the true is in parentheses means true needs to be a variable. and there's no difference with my code so doesn't help.

Comment: isnt that literally the same thing

Comment: You might want to learn the basics of Python before you answer any basic question.

Comment: You should look into the basics of Python before answering questions. This answer does the same as the OP's code